# Spring boot Controller is reusing same HttpServletRequest install for all requests (deployed on Tomcat)

Tags: spring-boot, servlets, httprequest

Hi have spring boot project and controller like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value= "/test")
public class AuthenticationController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/ping", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String ping(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String result = "HttpServletRequest.hashCode(): " + request.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

}
```

All requests from REST client of browser to API /test/ping return same value for `HttpServletRequest.hashCode()`.

Why does it happen? I researched tons of information on the internet, but can't find the reason of that. 
The only info I found says "servlet container to create and manage HttpServletRequest and response objects and reuse them". But it has to be not all the time, it happens each request, no matter how much I wait.

Below some setup info:
Deployed on Tomcat 8.5
servlet.xml

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" compression="on" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false"
                 maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="550" minSpareThreads="25" port="443"
                 protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https" secure="true"
                 sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLImplementation">
          <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol"/>
          <SSLHostConfig certificateVerification="none"
                         ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
                         protocols="TLSv1.2">

              <Certificate
                      certificateKeyAlias="*hidden"
                      certificateKeystoreFile="hidden"
                      certificateKeystorePassword="hidden" type="RSA" />
          </SSLHostConfig>
            
      </Connector>
```

Host

```
 <Host appBase="hidden" name="hidden.net">
            <Context docBase="../somewebapp" path="/webapp" reloadable="false"/>
            </Context>
      </Host>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>**hidden**</groupId>
    <artifactId>**hidden**</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>**hidden**</name>
    <description>**hidden**</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tests: Selenium & TestNG -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src\test\resources\suites\RegressionSuite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Could be a case of browser caching. Try it from an incognito window and also from a REST client like postman. Also, print all the request headers being received and sent from both server and client browser. Check for `Cache-Control`. In it's default state it can look into the browser http cache and get the request from there. Unless you specify it not to do that. Check this article for [more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache).

Comment: No, browser caching, because I clear all data, cache, history, everything and do a request even from different browsers on different machines, connected to different internet providers. Still get same instance of HttpServletRequest (((

Comment: And yes I print all request headers, there are no cookies sent from REST client

Comment: Do you use a proxy? If yes, maybe the proxy server might be caching them... I ran your code in my environment. It returns different values in mine. So this should definitely be an env issue.

Comment: Good point! Yes, I use proxy (even for the App deployed on local machine). But the thing is, when I put Debug breakpoint on line: "String result = **"HttpServletRequest.hashCode(): ' + request.hashCode();"** inside /ping API, each time I make requests from different browsers or REST clients it hits this breakpoint but all the time result variable has same value. Which means that proxy is not caching this API, otherwise debug breakpoint whouldn't hit, right?

Comment: I didn't understand your point exactly, so correct me If I misunderstood you. About the breakpoint, it will hit regardless of the client. Regarding the usage of different client calls and still getting the same, I believe you still use these clients inside your proxy. So it is highly likely that the culprit could be the proxy behavior (as I think). It's best if you can  set the necessary `cache-control` values (try `no-cache`) to your request using a rest client and check the behavior.

Comment: you understood me correctly, yes I get same value regardless of client with I call API ex. https://blabla.net/ping . So on all clients (browsers of REST client) I get returned from API string HttpServletRequest.hashCode(): 1112311666. The value will be all the time same.

Comment: Well, regarding Proxy, then I don't understand, why each time I call this API it will hit the breakpoint in this ping Controller. Normally, if Proxy caches something, it will not pass request further to server, but right away will return cached value to Client, no?

Comment: And one more thing, I just created brand new SpringBoot project (with similar configuration) and same /ping API, and now I see expected behaviour: Hash code always different. Here is URL, you can try on the browser or REST client: http://gatin.ca:8080/todoapp/api/test/ping

Comment: Ah, not I got what you are saying. Yes, the endpoint should not be reached if the proxy is caching the request.

Comment: Yeah the endpiont works fine now. Maybe it's a build issue I guess? Maybe it was using an old build to run the application or something?

Comment: This is new endpoint, I just created new SpringBoot app and deployed on different server. The one that doesn't work properly - I can't share the URl to /ping API. It still returns same number, issue is not solved yet.

Comment: just added pom.xml setup to main Post